# Laravel: Show category list by specifying parent category

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am trying to display categories in table. Here is what table structure I want to use in view file.

Category         |    Parent Category
Shirts               Clothes
Watch               NA

Here is my Database table structure

[image]

As you can see, parent category column contains ID of Parent category. SO if I fetch and display data in table then I gets ID in `Parent Category` comumn instead of name.

I am trying to find a solution in which I get name of parent category instead of ID.

I made this kind of Database table structure by thinking it is the professional table structure for category table. I can change Database table structure too if solution includes modifying table structure but it need to be look professional.

So is there a way out of it?
Thanks

Comment: Look for laravel relationship. Create a belongsto function in that model which will return the parent model itself.

Comment: @atikurrahman My categories and sub categories are in same database table. In my given screenshot, those categories who has `Null` in `parent_category` column are the parent category itself. So laravel relationship need more than 1 db table I guess.

Comment: This will not be a problem for same table. Just relate it with same model.

Comment: @atikurrahman woah, I never even thought anything like this. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @atikurrahman Self join worked well, Thanks, You can post this as answer ^^

Comment: Glad could helped :) . also added as answer :) . Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for laravel relationship. Create a belongsto function in that model which will return the parent model itself.Just relate it with same model.
you can refer self, using $this

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    function parentCategory(){
        return $this->hasMany($this, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Look into the docs for more Laravel build in model relationship , its awesome.

Comment: You can also use self class as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Actually I didn't use this method to solve my issue. What I did was after hearing your suggestion, I make query by using self join. I join my table with same table. I didn't add any function in model file. So if you add an laravel query of self join then I will accept your answer coz self join query helped me out here. But sure +1 for now for helping me out.

Comment: @Rishabh actually what you did is the regular process of mysql and that i provided is the laravel way which works actually same. I suggest you as you are using laravel go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table name is categories so You can try this in core php query 
**This will give you parent_category_name in a separate column**

```
select c.*, (select category from categories where id = c.parent_category) as parent_category_name from categories as c
```

**An below query will give you parent_category name at the place of parent_category_id**

```
select id, category, category_slug, (select category from categories where id = c.parent_category) as parent_category from categories as c
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this relationship to your Category model (Category.php)

```
public function parentCategory () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'parent_category');
}
```

You can now load your category with parent category data using `with()` method in your CategoryController.php

```
$categories = Category::with('parentCategory')->get();
```

In your blade file you can now do something like

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->parentCategory->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a relationship on `Category` model like this:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'parent_category');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I am not Laravel expert yet, just beginner. So I am not sure where to use this. As per my guess, I use this in controller function. But if I return your given code in function then where I will return view file. It would be nice if you elaborate your code so beginner like me can understand :)

Comment: Just read document
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships